# jquery validation form requires double click

Tags: jquery, validation

I have some code that is giving me a problem. The form that this jquery is attached to requires a double-click for some reason. I did some research and learned about the submit event handler, but as you can see from the code, I do not have it. I just want the form to submit without requiring 2 clicks by the user. Thanks in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function func1(field,message) {
        $(field).hover(function() {
            $('#submenu').stop().fadeIn();
            $('#submenu').html(message);
        }, function() {
            $('#submenu').stop().fadeOut();
        });
    }
    func1('#first_name','This is the first name field.');
    func1('#last_name','This is the last name field.');
    func1('#username','Username may be letters and numbers.');
    func1('#password','This is the password field. Please remember to include at least one special character and one number in your password.');
    func1('#email','Please insert a valid e-mail address.');
    $('#customerForm').validate({
        rules: {
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
                rangelength:[1,50],
                remote: "/nwrs8-20-2015/php_validation_scripts/check_email_field.php"
            },
            password: {
                required: true,
                rangelength:[6,18],
                remote: "/nwrs8-20-2015/php_validation_scripts/check_password_field.php"
            },
            username: {
                required: true,
                rangelength:[6,18],
                remote: "/nwrs8-20-2015/php_validation_scripts/check_username_field.php"
            },
            last_name: {
                required: true,
                rangelength:[1,50],
                remote: "/nwrs8-20-2015/php_validation_scripts/check_last_name_field.php"
            },
            first_name: {
                required: true,
                rangelength:[1,50],
                remote: "/nwrs8-20-2015/php_validation_scripts/check_first_name_field.php"
            },
            date_paid: {
                required: true,
                rangelength:[8,10],
                remote: "/nwrs8-20-2015/php_validation_scripts/check_date_paid.php"
            },
            membership_expiration: {
                required: true,
                rangelength:[8,10],
                remote: "/nwrs8-20-2015/php_validation_scripts/check_date_expired.php"
            }
        }
    })

});
```

Comment: where is your html code. consider making a fiddle.

Comment: Sorry man, could u try indenting as well, its hard to read and I get distracted following along with the logic

Comment: Nothing in the code you posted would cause that, there must be something else doing it.

Comment: going purely off what's shown I'd say it's your `hover` event handler that's still in the call stack when you click too soon.

Comment: Deryck could you please tell me how I would go about negating the effects of the hover event handler?

Comment: I don't think I can do a fiddle, because I wouldn't be able to link remotely to the PHP files. At least that's what I assume from what I've read and seen on jsfiddle.

Comment: I'm still having some trouble with this.

Answer (score 0):

Now that I look at it again it does seem to be going through one the first click. It's strange, sometimes I could swear it takes 2 clicks, but maybe the thing is just taking a while to process.